# Javascript compare set with string in apex page

Tags: apex, javascript, visualforce-component, visualforce, actionfunction

I have below apex page snippet where javascript fails to execute and errors out whole page because of failing to compare. Can someone help me here? Here intersects come from controller which I checked in debug log having desired value . Issue is with below line

```
if(intersects.contains({!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}))
```

Page snippet:

```
 if(count == 0 ){
                          if(intersects.contains({!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}))
                             { retSurveydetailResult += '<hr/> \n <hr> testing Rated Surveys <hr/> \n';
                             retSurveydetailResult +=  '<tr><td><b>'+ question +'</b></td><td><b>' + questRes + '</b></td></tr>';
                             }
       else {  retSurveydetailResult += '<hr/> \n <hr>  Rated Surveys <hr/> \n';
                                      retSurveydetailResult +=  '<tr><td><b>'+ question +'</b></td><td><b>' + questRes + '</b></td></tr>';
                                  }
                         }
```

Comment: I think u need to use .indexOf() method..
**if(intersects.indexOf({!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}) > -1){
code goes here ..
}**

Comment: Not working. Just shows a blank popup page for javascript

Comment: whats is intersects ?

Comment: A list or set coming from controller

Comment: ok ... then try this  **if({!intersects}.indexOf({!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}) > -1){ code goes here .. }**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use indexOf and quotes

```
if(intersects.indexOf('{!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}') > -1){
    //you code here
}
```

Comment: Not working. Just shows a blank popup page for javascript

Answer (score 0):

What if you display `{!qr.Survey_Target_vod__r.Name}` in an apex output text or in the page ? Is it blank ?

Is it populated since page load or do you need to perform a callback to the server to populate it ? If you, you may want to reRender the area where your JS code is written.

What if you inspect code ? Do you see something like :
`if(intersects.indexOf('theSurveyTargetName') > -1) { /*...*/ }` ?